# nuxt!доступ к localstorage

Tags: express, axios, nuxt.js

У меня Nuxt приложение с backend на express.

Мне нужно при первой загрузке странице получать access token.

Одно из решений перейти на хранение токена в cookie, но у меня не получается  получить данные, кажется что данные остаются где то в промежуточном этапе (chrome -> nuxt -> express)`только предполложение`.

axios.interceptors.response пытаюсь перехватить данные здесь

Если не сложно приведите пример с конкретным кодом

Answer (score 0):

рекомендую использовать "Хранилище Vuex". Подробное описание можно найти в 
документации: https://ru.nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/

для примера может служить скрипт ниже. store/index.js

```
export const state = () => ({
    token: null
})

export const mutations = {
    setToken(state, token) {
        state.token = token
    },
    clearToken(state) {
        state.token = null
    }
}

export const actions = {
    login({ commit }) {
        commit('setToken', 'truetoken')
    },
    logout({ commit }) {
        commit('clearToken')
    },
}

export const getters = {
    hasToken: s => !!s.token
}
```